# How should I change my OpenGL app to use the iOS 11 safe area?

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, ios11, iphone-x

I maintain an OpenGL app that's been running on iOS since 2010. It uses the full screen and hides the status bar. It launches without any .nib file and creates an OpenGL view & controller that, in turn, displays all app content.

What changes do I need to make so the app will work on iPhone X using the new 'safe area' layout design?  Presumably the only real change is just creating my "EAGL" surface/view with the same dimensions and location as the safe area instead of the entire screen?

Answer (score 1):

How you respect the safe area in a "fullscreen" app (like most GL, Metal, etc games) is really two questions: one of design, and one of implementation. (But it's easier to tackle them in the reverse of that order, so here goes...)

#### Making fullscreen OpenGL views

If you have a fullscreen view (e.g. the window's root view controller) and you just set its `layerClass` to `CAEAGLLayer` (as is par for the course in most OpenGL ES work), you get a view that covers the entire 1125 x 2436 rectangle of the iPhone X screen. (Be sure to set the scale, too, so you actually get all those pixels... 375 x 812 @ 1x scale probably looks hideous on that screen.)

That's probably the user experience you want for your app/game (and it's the one [Apple encourages](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017/801/))... your 3D content extends all the way to the edges of the screen, around the curves at the bottom and the  at the top. That makes a much nicer UX than leaving black borders around all your content.

#### Designing fullscreen content for iPhone X

On the other hand, the existing design of how your OpenGL *content* appears may or may not fit well with the curiously shaped screen of iPhone X. If you have anything along the very top that the user is expected to see, it'll be obscured behind the camera/sensor/speaker cutout. Similarly, if you have anything important at the bottom, its edges will be cut off behind the curved corners.

In that case, you'll want to leave the unimportant parts of your fullscreen content (like a game's view of a 3D gameplay world) fullscreen, but inset any important content like UI overlays or interactive 3D elements. As for how you might do that, there's a couple of feasible approaches, with tradeoffs:

- Hard-code the iPhone X obstruction dimensions, detect when you're running on iPhone X, and fix your layout accordingly. This is straightforward, but not robust. If Apple decides to change the way software UI elements around screen edges (like the swipe-to-home indicator) work, or makes iPhone XI (or X2? or XX?) next year with a slightly different shape, you'll need to update again to adapt.
- Use the Safe Area guides even though you're not using UIKit or Auto Layout to draw/position onscreen content. Ask the view for its [`safeAreaLayoutGuide`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891102-safearealayoutguide) and convert that guide's bounds to whatever coordinate system you use for positioning the content you draw with OpenGL. This is a little more work, but it ensures that your app is ready for any curveballs Apple throws in the future.

#### One more thing...

> It uses the full screen and hides the status bar.

When designing for iPhone X, it's worth rethinking whether a "fullscreen" app should hide the status bar. On other iOS devices, showing the status bar means taking away useful space from your app's content. But on iPhone X, most apps don't have anything useful they can do with those "devil horn" corners anyway — your user might appreciate still being able to see the clock, battery, etc.